# How to join with dataset with column as the collection of keys to join by?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, left-join

I'm trying to figure out how to join two Dataframes where one of the dataframes contains a list that has the key to join by.

For example:

- one dataframe has the format `(id: String, ...,...)`
- the other has `(... ,..., List[tmpObj])`
- `tmpObj` is structured like this `(id: String, value: int)`.

My goal is to join the two dataframes by the id values found in the second dataFrame's list of tmpObj to the id from the first dataframe.

Does anyone have any idea of how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write an UDF to check whether the list contains the given id:

```
val df1 = Seq("a","b","c").toDF("id")

case class TmpObject(id:String,value:Int)

val df2 = Seq(
  Seq(
    TmpObject("a",1),
    TmpObject("c",2)
  )
).toDF("list")

val arrayContains = udf((xs:Seq[String],s:String) => xs.contains(s))

df1.join(df2,arrayContains($"list.id",$"id"),"left")
  .show()


+---+--------------+
| id|          list|
+---+--------------+
|  a|[[a,1], [c,2]]|
|  b|          null|
|  c|[[a,1], [c,2]]|
+---+--------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Can use the built-in SQL function `array_contains`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df1.join(df2, expr("array_contains(list.id, id)"), "left")
```

**NOTE**: you may be tempted to try using the `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array_config` directly (not within a call to `expr`, i.e. `df1.join(df2, array_contains($"list.id", $"id"), "left")`), but that won't do in this case, as its signature limits its usage to cases where the second argument is some constant value (expects `Any` but fails if the argument's type is `Column`).

Comment: @Jacek-Laskowski thanks for the edit, but I think it's wrong - first, `list.id` and `id` are not defined, will have to be changed to `$"list.id"` and `$"id"`, but that won't work either because the signature of `array_contains` does not expect a _Column_ as the second argument but rather a "constant" value; It seems that the _method_ `array_contains` and the _SQL function_ by the same name actually differ in that sense (the method narrows the functions' capabilities). I'll revert this edit unless I hear from you first :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `explode` and `join` the first dataframe on `id`:

```
df2.withColumn("obj", explode($"list_obj")).
  join(df1, $"obj.id" === $"id", "right")
```